# fastai Machine Learning Course: Version issue

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

Recently I started this Machine learning (http://course18.fast.ai/ml.html) course. The code provided here is in the old version of fastai (0.7.0). Is there any way that I can run these code with the current version of fastai?

(I'm on ubuntu 19.10 and used to code at google colab).

Comment: What happens when you try to run them?

Comment: Please see this...
[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/XAMatth.png) @erip